# Activate specific element In Array?

Tags: unity

In my array there are 6 elements "guns" and I want to activate one element after deactivate all of them. Here is my script

```
public saveInfo _file; // get gun ID number from save file.
public GameObject Player1_pistol;
public GameObject[] pl1_p; // 6 guns

void Start()
{
    pl1_p = new GameObject[Player1_pistol.transform.childCount];
    for (int p = 0; p < Player1_pistol.transform.childCount; p++)
    {
        pl1_p[p] = Player1_pistol.transform.GetChild(p).gameObject;
        pl1_p[p].SetActive(false);
      // Now I need to activate the third element in my array.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by getting the number from the save file and use it inside for function or outside it.

```
// inside for function
        pl1_p[p].SetActive(p == "get number from save file");
// outside 
        pl1_p["get the number from save file"].SetActive(true);
```

Good luck.